# get all users who are not following the user 2

Tags: php, mysql

**Example:** I want to get all users who do not follow the id 2 user

Table Followers

```
   id     |   user_id   |  follower_id

    1            2             7
    2            2             8
```

Table users

```
id  |  username  | e-mail  | group
```

Comment: Shouldn't you detail in which language you'd expect the answer: sql or php way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Select users.* 
from users 
where users.id not in (
    select followers.follower_id 
    from followers 
    where followers.user_id = "2"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked perfectly!

Comment: Please accept this answer as the correct one then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mysql expert but I believe a pseudo-sql would be:

```
select users.* from users where users.id is in (select distinct follower_id from followers where followers.user_id != 2)
```

The **!=** means **different**.

Comment: The result returns with multiple users repeated 

https://image.prntscr.com/image/T-iRabAaQg_9Jzshg02luQ.png

Comment: I've changed the pseudo-sql.

Comment: You can use **distinct** to remove duplicates.

Comment: This option wont work, because if user id 1 follows user id 3 and 2 then your statement will still show user id 1 not following user 2. I posted the correct answer which will solve for this. Very close though srodriguex!!